# undefined symbol: PyInstanceMethod_Type when trying to import pybind into a makefile c++ project

Tags: c++, makefile, pybind11

I am using pybind11 in my makefile. I added all the header files to my project for pybind11. I am getting the error:

Error /home/vagrant/ss/bt/strategies_dlls/PybindStrategy.so: undefined symbol: PyInstanceMethod_Type

What am I doing wrong? I am compiling into a .so file that is used in another project.

Here is a portion of my makefile

```
INCLUDES=-I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I$(INCLUDEPATH)
LDFLAGS=$(LIBPATH)/libstrategystudio_analytics.a $(LIBPATH)/libstrategystudio.a $(LIBPATH)/libstrategystudio_transport.a $(LIBPATH)/libstrategystudio_marketmodels.a $(LIBPATH)/libstrategystudio_utilities.a $(LIBPATH)/libstrategystudio_flashprotocol.a
LIBRARY=PybindStrategy.so

SOURCES=PybindStrat.cpp
HEADERS=PybindStrat.h
 
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(HEADERS) $(LIBRARY)

$(LIBRARY) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(LIBRARY).1 -o $(LIBRARY) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: That symbol is part of python C API https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/method.html#c.PyInstanceMethod_Type , so you need to link with `libpython.x.yy.so`. But in general better just build it with CMake https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-with-cmake and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: @pptaszni Thank you for your help! I fixed it by adding -lpython3.8 to my ld flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding -lpython3.8 to my ld flags in the makefile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).